# My answer had a space added, then removed. Why would someone perform these edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

I wrote an 8-line program to answer a question someone had; I found it had been edited, and was curious what someone had done to it. It turns out the person added a space to the end of the 8 lines, then removed that space.

So that person now appears as having "edited" the question. I don't know whether having his name appear on the page is worth that much, or whatever rep you get by editing questions, or what, but it seems odd to me. Can someone explain why someone would do this?

[Edit history on the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53462549/revisions)

Comment: Maybe they made a mistake? They did rollback after all. You can @-reply to the editor by the way, so you can ask him your self

Comment: Have you seen any score fluctuations in the answer? It could be a dummy edit so that the user could reconsider a vote.

Comment: On a different note: don't you think an answer becomes more useful with a bit of explanation instead of a code-only dump?

Comment: Also note that making edits does not give reputation once you have 2k reputation.

Comment: @rene is there an @-reply that becomes a PM instead of a comment? I don't try to use SO that way much, so I honestly don't know. As to the post, it really seemed to me that the code was a complete answer, I thought it would be overkill to explain that a `public void static main()` could call other `public void static main()` methods when the code doing so was sitting right there.

Comment: No, you can't send private messages to users. That is very much by design.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't mean to scare you.

I downvoted your post because I believed it was a low-quality answer*. Later I got back to the question and noticed that it didn't receive much attention. I reviewed your answer again and came to the conclusion that the idea, in general, is correct. So I decided to get my vote back by a slight edit of the answer.

*I still don't think the answer is good. I'll elaborate on that in the thread on SO.

Comment: Well, question was "What is the easiest way to combine these so they run 1 and than the other." My answer successfully shows exactly how to do this, and I do not know and have not seen (and cannot imagine) an easier way to do it. I didn't think it needed elaboration. I'll look for your comments on low quality over in SO. It's nice to have an answer to my question here, i.e., that you edited in order to change your downvote.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere on Meta that editing a post for the sole purpose of reverting your vote is **not** fine.

Comment: What’s another way to get your vote back?

Comment: OK, after some research, trivial edits got apparently permitted by a founder of Stack Overflow, while at the same time strongly disapproved by the community, as seen by the votes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-an-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left/21839#21839. I do believe that repetitive trivial edits may be  flagged for moderator attention, so better avoid those empty edits as much as possible.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to do anything.

The user is not doing for rep or badges (they do not gain rep for edits at their rep level, and they seem to be pretty stablished as to be doing petty edits for worthless badges).

It looks like they made a mistake and rolled it back.

Or it could be as someone else suggested: Maybe they had voted on your post and wanted to undo their vote for whatever reason: since votes lock after five minutes but unlock after an edit; this would be a way to get around that restriction.

Again, pretty harmless.

If it really, really irks you to see someone elses name in your post, in this case you could roll-back to the first version.

But really, why care for something like this at all?

Comment: It seems an odd sort of mistake to make for someone very familiar with the site.

Comment: @arcy you can make silly mistakes at **any** experience (or reputation) level. But even then, there is also the possibility of wanting to undo a vote. I've updated my answer. In any case, it's not something to worry about.

Comment: I wasn't worrying about it; I was curious as to why. Edit-person has responded now.